# How to lookup one model in with other in Groovy?

Tags: hibernate, groovy, hibernate-mapping

I have two model classes in my project. Now I need to lookup one model class with other. Please refer the following shared code.

**Lead Model Class,**

```
package model
@Entity @NavModuleClass
class Leads {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    String firstName, lastName
    Date dateOfActivity
    //def task = Tasks.newInstance() Throwing error
    }
```

**Task model class,**

```
package model
@Entity @NavModuleClass
class Tasks {

    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private long id;
    String taskName, taskCreatedBy, lastModifiedBy
    Date taskStartDate, taskEndDate, lastModifiedDate

}
```

I need to lookup the Task model class in Lead. How can I do that. I tried to create the instance in Lead class with following code `def task = Tasks.newInstance()` but it throwing some error. Give me some suggestion to do the same.

Comment: `Tasks task` doesn't work? why don't u use a simple declaration plus constructor call

Comment: I tried Task task but I got the following errors 1) javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: Main] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory 2) org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: model.Tasks, at table: Leads, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(task)].

Comment: How can I use a simple declaration plus constructor call? Can you give me simple example. I am new to groovy.

Comment: are you using groovy or grails? u taged the question as grails! u should tag it hibernate and groovy i don't think u are working on a grails application! i am nat fammiliar with just groovy

Comment: Yes I am using groovy. Anyways thank you for your response